# Rank or Dense_Rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to assign a "section" to the numbers below. Not sure if Dense_Rank will even work.  Basically it should assign by seq and UniqueLoc.  So it should look at seq 0 then UniqueLoc 99137-4529 and assign section 1 then move to seq 1 if the UniqueLoc matches it should assign section 1 if not then section 2. Below is my SQL and my Results:  As you can see it is doing the Dense rank but not in the order I need them.  It should be 1, 2, 3, 3

```
UniqueLoc   seq loadnumber  SwineMovement   sectionrow  section
99137-4529  0   304360             304360          1     2
99137-4530  1   304360             3043601         1     1
99079-4530  2   304360             3043602         1     3
99079-4530  3   304360             3043603         2     3

select *,
DENSE_RANK () over ( partition by loadnumber, uniqueloc order by   seq )   as sectionrow ,
DENSE_RANK () over (  partition by Loadnumber   order by     uniqueloc desc )   as section 
from test
order by loadnumber, seq
```

---

```
    UniqueLoc   seq loadnumber  SwineMovement   dr  WHAT I NEED
    99137-4529  0   304360             304360   3   1
    99137-4530  1   304360            3043601   4   2
    99079-4530  2   304360            3043602   5   3
    99079-4530  3   304360            3043603   5   3
     2519-3982  0   304468            304468    2   1
     2632-3982  1   304468           3044681    1   2
   104004-8232  0   304873            304873    8   1
    104004-8232 1   304873           3048731    8   1
   104007-8035  2   304873           3048732    6   2
    104007-8035 3   304873           3048733    6   2
    104007-8232 4   304873           3048734    7   3
    104007-8232 5   304873           3048735    7   3
```

Comment: Update your question and tell us which database (e.g. SQL Server, Postgres) you are using.

Comment: Include your data in the question by adding _four_ spaces to each line of data.  This will format the data as code which is monospaced and easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your expected result, the ordering would always be on seq column

```
SELECT uniqueloc,
       seq,
       loadnumber,
       swinemovement,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY loadnumber 
                              ORDER BY CASE WHEN seq<> rnum
                                            THEN CONCAT(CAST(seq-rnum AS VARCHAR),uniqueloc)
                                            ELSE uniqueloc
                                        END) [rank]
  FROM (SELECT *,
               (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loadnumber 
                                       ORDER BY uniqueloc) - 1) rnum
          FROM t_load
       ) t
 ORDER BY loadnumber, 
          seq;
```

Result (I added test data loadnumber 900000 to check if the ranking is still true to other scenario)

```
uniqueloc   seq loadnumber  swinemovement   rank
99137-4529  0   304360      304360          1
99137-4530  1   304360      3043601         2
99079-4530  2   304360      3043602         3
99079-4530  3   304360      3043603         3
2519-3982   0   304468      304468          1
2632-3982   1   304468      3044681         2
104004-8232 0   304873      304873          1
104004-8232 1   304873      3048731         1
104007-8035 2   304873      3048732         2
104007-8035 3   304873      3048733         2
104007-8232 4   304873      3048734         3
104007-8232 5   304873      3048735         3
99137-4529  0   900000      304360          1
99079-4530  1   900000      3043601         2
99079-4530  2   900000      3043602         2
99137-4530  3   900000      3043603         3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the ordering should be first by the last four digits in the `UniqueLoc` column ascending, followed by the first five digits of the same column descending:

```
SELECT *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY loadnumber
                       ORDER BY
                           SUBSTRING(UniqueLoc,
                           CHARINDEX('-', UniqueLoc) + 1,
                           LEN(UniqueLoc) - CHARINDEX('-', UniqueLoc)),
                           SUBSTRING(UniqueLoc, 1, CHARINDEX('-', UniqueLoc) - 1) DESC) dr
FROM test
ORDER BY
    loadnumber, seq;
```

You never told us your database, but if it supports `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions, then you could just use the following cleaner `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY RIGHT(UniqueLoc, 4), LEFT(UniqueLoc, 5) DESC
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

The demo is in SQL Server, because your `select *` syntax would fail on Oracle I think, leaving Postgres as probably the only other candidate.

Comment: Maybe `Partition by` here is not necessary?

Comment: @LONG I think you're right, I'm trying to add a demo now.

Comment: That works for this but once I add more loads to the table it doesn't work.  I am creating another date set to include on this.  It will be a few minutes

Comment: UniqueLoc seq loadnumber SwineMovement dr
     99137-4529 0 304360 304360 3
     99137-4530 1 304360 3043601 4
     99079-4530 2 304360 3043602 5
      99079-4530 3 304360 3043603 5
       2519-3982 0 304468 304468 7
       2632-3982 1 304468 3044681 6
      104004-8232 0 304873 304873 2
    104004-8232 1 304873 3048731 2
    104007-8035 2 304873 3048732 1
   104007-8035 3 304873 3048733 1
   104007-8232 4 304873 3048734 2
   104007-8232 5 304873 3048735 2

Comment: Did you not see my above comment?  Update your question with the database type, and your new data.  I cannot answer to your updated data without knowing the species of database you are using.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time posting and I am not sure how to format the comments in a table.

Comment: Database is SQL

Comment: SQL Server? Postgres? Oracle? Something else?

Comment: Database is SQL Server.

Comment: @T.Noe I gave an update which uses the hyphen separator in the `UniqueLoc` column to extract the two numbers which appear before and after that hyphen.  This should cover your actual data as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Tim hyphen separator did not work.  I have updated my question with another set of data with multi loads and column that show what I need it to be.  Thanks

Comment: Updated again.  By the way, your expected output is wrong.

Comment: Tim, That is not working.  My expected output is what I need. dr 1 should always be seq 0 for a load.   Basically It first needs group by loadnumber  then sort by seq then start numbering.  The number should change for every change in uniqueLoc

Comment: `That is not working` ... um, yes it is, check the demo.